# Database to DataGridView floating point error or non-trimmed trailing zeros

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview

My current project requires displaying some numbers in a DataGridView column in a Windows Forms front end. The numbers can then be editted and are sent back to the database to be updated. All values are between 0 and 0.5. For the user's sake, I wish all trailing zeros to be removed, but accuracy is also important so a value of 0.123456789 should be stored to full precision.

I had been using a SQL float to store the numbers, passing them to doubles in C#. This would result in the correct output, with trialing zeros removed (e.g. 0.2, 0.123, 0.432105). The problem was that some values were being inaccurately passed (e.g. 0.208 was being returned as 0.2080000002) due to a floating point error.

To solve this, I changed to using decimal data types in both the database and the front end. However, all values are now displayed to the maximum number of defined decimal places (eg. 0.200000, 0.123000, 0.432105).

The possible solutions I can see are:

- Removing trialing zeros from the decimal in the DataGridView.

  Though,

  ```
  dataGridView.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.#"
  ```

  doesn't appear to work.
- Passing the number accurately to a C# double, which will then automatically display the number in my preferred format.

though, I am unable to achieve either of these.

Is anyone able to assist me with this problem?

Comment: Floating point numbers *always* end up incurring rounding errors.  They are not infinitely accurate, they are explicitly a binary *approximation* when used to represent decimal numbers.  If you know that you need `n` decimal places of accuracy, use `DECIMAL` and not `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`.  There are many articles on this on the web, here is just one of them: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: I am well aware of this. SQL had no trouble displaying the numbers correctly, however the error only occurred when passing to C# (and only a few at that). This is the reason I changed to decimal data types, however I now have this formatting issue. Can you assist with this?

Comment: You have set the `.DefaultCellStyle.Format`, but have you set the `.ValueType`?  *(For example, to `GetType(Decimal)`?)*  And have you tried format `"G"`?

Comment: Format "G" didn't work. I'm using this to define the column at the moment: dataTable.Columns.Add("Amount", System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal")); then I set this as the DataSource.

Answer (score 0):

> private char[] _noZero = new char[] {'0'};
>
> textBox1.Text = l.fieldOfDecimalType.ToString().TrimEnd(_noZero);